# Postgis ST_Distance_Sphere giving about 1.7 too high result

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am new into Postgis and spatial stuff and I am struggling with quite simple query.

I have two records in `places` for test, where column `addressLocation` is a POINT with following values:

```
(51.122711,17.031819)
(51.122805,17.035522)
```

I am trying to make a query:

```
SELECT *
FROM places
WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere("addressLocation"::geometry, ST_MakePoint(51.122711, 17.033686)) <= 255;
```

`51.122711, 17.033686` Is about in the center between both of these points and distance measured on Google maps is about 125 and 128 meters.

The issue is that `(51.122805,17.035522)` got into results with `205` as limit and the other one with `210`.

I was looking through the PostGIS docs and cannot find any explanation for such inaccuracy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coordinates in PostGIS must be expressed as longitude/latitude, while in Google Map they are expressed as latitude/longitude.

Your query is computing distances in Yemen:

```
Select ST_DistanceSphere(st_geomFromText('POINT(51.122711 17.031819)'),
st_geomFromText('POINT(51.122711 17.033686)'));
 st_distancesphere
-------------------
      207.60121386
```

While by swapping the coordinates, the points are in Poland and the distance is:

```
Select ST_DistanceSphere(st_geomFromText('POINT(17.031819 51.122711)'),
 st_geomFromText('POINT(17.033686 51.122711)'));
 st_distancesphere
-------------------
      130.30184168
```

Comment: Silly me! Thank you. I am not sure if I should be afraid you that quickly figured out I am from Poland...

Comment: :-) it is in your profile, and the coordinates make sense there

Comment: ;) I know. Just kidding. Thanks for your help

Comment: Note that st_distancespheroid is a little slower, requires a spheroid as an argument but is more accurate.